# Split string into char list recursively

Tags: .net, string, recursion, f#

I'm trying to split a string into a char list recursively. This what I have to far:

```
let rec explode2 (s: string) =
  match s with 
  | "" -> []
  | s ->
    let newWord = s.[1..]
    let newArr = List.ofArray(newWord.ToCharArray())
    explode2 newWord
    newArr
```

Am I going in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first part is right (for returning a list not an array):

```
  match s with 
  | "" -> []
```

it takes care of the empty string case which in a recursive function is the end case.

For the second part you need to:

- separate the first character from the rest of the string.
- call the function with the rest of the string.
- concatenate the first character with the returned list.

To concatenate an element to a list you can use the `::` operator:

```
c :: lst
```

You are getting there, so keep at it.

Comment: Thanks! This is the solution I came up with and it works but I'm not really sure what is happening on the last line, could you maybe explain?

`let rec explode2 (s: string) =
  match s with 
  | "" -> []
  | s -> explode2 (s.Remove(0,1))
         List.ofArray(s.ToCharArray())`

Comment: `s.ToCharArray()`  is the built in function to do exactly what you want. The rest of  the code is actually doing nothing. Also, it is producing a `List` instead of an array, that is because `List.ofArray` converts an array to a list.

Comment: Right, thank you! It is my mistake the function should return a `char list` not an array.

Comment: Ok, I changed the answer for returning a list instead.

Comment: I left it as an exercise. I was trying to be enigmatic.